# Query Laravel Select Where Array

Tags: mysql, laravel, select

I have a users table. Inside there is a column called `city_id`.
Inside the `city_id` column data are stored like this :for ex:`["12,54,87,18"]`
Now I want to select user/users whose `city_id` exists or is equal to the `$postcity` variable.
for ex:

```
$postcity = 54;
```

my code for select:

```
$usermatchings = DB::table('users')
                                    
                ->Where('city_id', $postcity )
                                
                ->get();
                foreach ($usermatchings as $usermatching) {
                $recipients = $usermatching->phone; 
                }
                dd($recipients);
```

but not working... please guide me.thank you

Comment: You should consider reorganizing structure by making `cities` table and associating manyToMany relations (along with `city_user` table) where you would store current relations. It would speed up things a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

- datatype or the `city_id` column is `json`
- cast is defined on the model
- not using sqlite as database

```php
class User extends Model
{
    protected $casts = ['city_id' => 'array'];
}
```

You can use whereJsonContains

```php
$usermatchings = DB::table('users')
    ->whereJsonContains('city_id', $postcity)
    ->get();

//To get an array of all phone (numbers)
$recepients = $usermatchings->pluck('phone')->all();
```

Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses

Comment: Yep! great, thank you. but Dump just one user`s phone (while I have many users equal this conditionals)

Comment: `pluck()` method is used on collection returned by the `get()` on query. So it will pluck the values for `phone` from all elements of collection and return a collection of just the values of phone. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck

Comment: I send `$recipients` to Twilio function for send sms;
`return ($this->sendMessageAmin($body, $recipients));`   but get error: `Argument 1 passed to Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\MessageList::create() must be of the type string, array given, called in `

Comment: this my function ` private  function sendMessageAmin($message, $recipients)
    {
        $account_sid = '****';
        $auth_token = '******';
        $twilio_number = '*******';
        $client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);
        $client->messages->create($recipients, ['from' => $twilio_number, 'body' => $message]);
    }`

Comment: Am not aware of the Twilio api, but if you need to send the recepients as string of comma separated values, you can use `join()` on collection instead of using `all()` to convert to array like `$recepients = $usermatchings->pluck('phone')->join(',');`

Comment: yes when add `join(',')` send sms but when has one user(one phone number) while has two users say error: `[HTTP 400] Unable to create record: The 'To' number +15416048147+15416042391 is not a valid phone number.`

Comment: You will have to look up Twilio api and if it accepts only one number at a time then you will probably have to loop through the array of $recepients to send the sms - sorry am not conversant with Twilio api

Answer (score 1):

You can use `like` as stated in [laravel query builder doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#basic-where-clauses). Below code may help you:

```
$usermatchings = DB::table('users')                      
    ->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(?,city_id)', [$postcity])
    ->get();
```

**Notice:** If you wanna save the result in an array, you should aggregate it, not override it.

```
foreach ($usermatchings as $usermatching) {
    $recipients[] = $usermatching->phone; 
}
```

Comment: This is not well solution and won't be reliable since it will return rows that contain `["540", "541", "542", "1054"]` etc.